# Ruby hash for Sparse Matrix

Tags: ruby, performance, oop, design-patterns, hash

I know that there are several [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730060/sparse-matrix-libraries-for-ruby) for it in Ruby. But I must create my own (for learning purposes).

I am considering two approaches for this:

A hash whereas the key is a string in the form

`myhash["row.col"]` so I can use the default value as zero when the element doesn't exist.

Or creating a Sparse class, then checking elements to return its value:

```
class SparseMatrix < Array
  require 'contracts'
  include Contracts
  attr_accessor :value, :array
  attr_reader :row, :col
  @@array = Array.new
  Contract Num, Num, Num =>  nil
  def initialize(value,row,col)
    @value = value
    @row = row
    @col = col
  end
  def self.all_instances
    @@array
  end
  Contract Num, Num =>  Num
  def getElement(row,col)
    flag = false
    array.each do |x|
      if x.row == row && x.col == col
        return x.value
      end
    end
    0
  end
end
```

I don't want this to be subjective, I wonder for the design patterns mostly used which would be a more logical format to do? (My question is because as much as "row.col" seems easier to begin with, it also involves several conversion from/to strings/numbers and it could have performance problems. ( I am new to ruby, so I am not sure)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the hash way because it's easy, fast to write, and fast to access.

For the hash key, use an array like this:

```
hash[[row,col]] = value
```

You can use anything for the row and col, such as a string, number, complex object, etc.

For learning purposes, you may be interesting in wrapping Hash:

```
class SparseMatrix

  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def [](row, col)
    @hash[[row, col]]
  end

  def []=(row, col, val)
    @hash[[row, col]] = val
  end

end
```

Usage:

```
matrix = SparseMatrix.new
matrix[1,2] = 3
matrix[1,2] #=> 3
```

For learning purposes, you can use as many dimensions as you like:

```
class SparseMatrix

  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def [](*keys)
    @hash[keys]
  end

  def []=(*keys, val)
    @hash[keys] = val
  end

end
```

Usage:

```
matrix = SparseMatrix.new
matrix[1,2,3,4] = 5
matrix[1,2,3,4] #=> 5
```

Comment: Very ruby-like and simple implementation Joel!